# Link HTTP request-response using netty4 async call

Tags: java, netty

I am writing a simple HTTP client using netty-4.0x. 
 Build the pipeline as below :

```
pipeline.addLast("codec", new HttpClientCodec());
pipeline.addLast("inflater", new HttpContentDecompressor());
pipeline.addLast("handler", new HttpResponseHandler());
```

where `HttpResponseHandler` provides implementation of `messageReceived()`,

Now there is a thread-pool which call the client and keep sending http message, 
I understand that `ChannelFuture future = channel.write(request);` is async call and will come out without blocking

The query which i am having is, is there a way to link request-response, without calling 
`future.sync()` call.

Thanks for all the help in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you code the server too, you could have the client add a unique id to the HTTP header and have the server echo it back in the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following strict HTTP pipelining rules then, on any given channel, the responses will be returned in the order the requests were sent in. It should be enough to maintain a request queue, removing the front of the queue for each response received.

If you are creating a new channel, and a new pipeline for that channel, for each request, it's even easier. Either way you can add a handler to your pipeline which remembers the request (or queue of requests), and returns the request and response to your application when the response is received.